# If value present, order posts by two consecutive custom fields

Tags: custom-field, order

Basically on my site I have a bunch of song lyrics and in a static page I want to show them listed by album [Link to my website](http://www.thenewblackgold.netsons.org/wp/indexes/by-album/) and album position of the song and I have two custom fields with that data, `sd_album_title` and `sd_album_track_n.
Plus some of the songs don't have an album yet, so both values are void, and I wish to list those ones at the foot of the others, sorted by alphabetical order. 
The latest thing I tried at least to sort everything by the two field is this one:

```
$key = 'sd_album_title';
$themeta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, TRUE);

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );
function my_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ($themeta != '') {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'lyric' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'sd_album_title' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
              array(
                    'key' => 'sd_album_title'
              ),
              array(
                    'key' => 'sd_album_track_n',
                    'value' => 'target_value',
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'type' => 'numeric'
              )
        ));
    }
    return $query;
}

$getlist= 'my_get_posts';
$posts = get_posts( $getlist );
```

And my intention was to put an else at the end of it with an array ordered by title for the other songs, but it returns nothing as it is.
Could something like this work with some corrections or am I on a totally wrong path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are using `pre_get_posts` when using your own `get_posts()` ? You can just pass the argument list directly to `get_posts()`.

`orderby` can accept array of arguments and can order by multiple values.
First name the indexes of meta queries array. This can be anything to use in orderby parameter. e.g.

```
'meta_query' => array(
        'album_title_meta' => array(
            'key' => 'sd_album_title',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        'album_track_n_meta' => array(
            'key' => 'sd_album_track_n',
            'value' => 'target_value',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'numeric'
        )
    ),
```

Then pass an array in `orderby`, constructed using these keys!

```
'orderby' => array(
        'album_title_meta' => 'ASC',
        'album_track_n_meta' => 'DESC',
    ),
```

First, posts will be order by album title, ASC then track number, DESC.

**The complete example:**

```
$my_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'lyric',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'album_title_meta' => array(
            'key' => 'sd_album_title',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        'album_track_n_meta' => array(
            'key' => 'sd_album_track_n',
            'value' => 'target_value',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'numeric'
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'album_title_meta' => 'ASC',
        'album_track_n_meta' => 'DESC',
    ),
);
$getlist = get_posts($my_args);
```

> NOTE: these syntax are only supported since WordPress [version
>   4.2](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_4.2)

Comment: Neat! I didn't know you could order by keys like that, +1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sumit now it all works well!
For anyone else that encounters the same problem: I also wished to put the singles (that don't have any album or album track data) at the bottom (even now I think I'll leave them at the top) and ordered by title. Instead of making an if / else, since the output should be different too, I decided to put two get_posts like this:

```
<?php 
//LIST ORDERED BY ALBUM 
//SINGLES SECTION - SHOWS SINGLES SORTED BY TITLE (Singles category is the n. 47)
$single_posts = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'     => 'lyric',
    'category' => 47,
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'orderby'=> 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC' )
    );

if( $single_posts ): ?>

    <ul>

    <?php foreach( $single_posts as $post ): 

        setup_postdata( $post )

        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">[Single]&nbsp;
<?php the_title(); ?> (<?php the_field('sd_song_time'); ?>)</a>
        </li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php 
//LIST ORDERED BY ALBUM 
//ALBUM SECTION - SHOWS ALBUMS SORTED BY TRACK N.
$album_posts = array(
    'post_type'     => 'lyric',
    'category__not_in' => 47,
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_query'    => array(
            'album_title_meta' => array(
        'key' => 'sd_album_title',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                 ),
            'album_track_n_meta' => array(
                'key' => 'sd_album_track_n',
                'value' => 'target_value',
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'numeric'
                 )
         ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'album_title_meta' => 'ASC',
        'album_track_n_meta' => 'ASC',
    ),
);

$posts = get_posts( $album_posts );

if( $posts ): ?>

    <ul>

    <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 

        setup_postdata( $post )

        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">
<?php the_field('sd_album_track_n'); ?>.&nbsp;<?php the_field('sd_album_title'); ?>:&nbsp;<?php the_title(); ?> (<?php the_field('sd_song_time'); ?>)</a>
        </li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I know probably there are better ways to do this, but it works like a charm ;)