# How to Order By Two Custom Fields?

Tags: wp-query, loop

Note : This is not a duplicate question to [If value present, order posts by two consecutive custom fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/222148/if-value-present-order-posts-by-two-consecutive-custom-fields). After filtering a custom filed, I need to order by another custom filed. (The above link explains filtering by two custom fields. But I need to filter by a custom filed and then order by another custom filed.

This is a my current wp query array.

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => array('post', 'video'),
 'meta_key' => 'pp_like_count',
 'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num',                        
);
```

I have order by custom filed called `pp_like_count`. This works fine.

But I need to display only *if `'pp_lang'` custom filed equals to 'english'*. How to modify this to add it?

(Order by `pp_like_count` also should be there.)

Comment: @toscho This is not a duplicate question to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/222148/if-value-present-order-posts-by-two-consecutive-custom-fields. After filtering a custom filed, I need to order by another custom filed. (The above link explains filtering by two custom fields. But I need to filter by a custom filed and then order by another custom filed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this by using meta query to filter results and then adding orderby to order results. Below arguments should work

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => array('post', 'video'),
 'meta_key' => 'pp_like_count',
 'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num',
 "meta_query" => array(            
        array(
            "key" => "pp_lang",
            "value" => "english",
            "type" => "CHAR",
            "compare" => "="
        ),
    ),                 
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would not works because I thought I can't use both meta_key and meta_query in same array. But it worked. Thanks :-)

Comment: never assume anything before trying :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use meta query see below link it will help you.

[How to order by meta field](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/)